# Getting the image xpath from trello public card

Tags: html, css, xpath

I want to get an image from a trello card cover into my email signature. Currently I add the static image URL using just html path to the image -

This is the board - https://trello.com/b/8ykctyqk/where-to-next-travel-inspiration-board

I'm trying to get the Card Cover Image of the second card in the list 'Bucketlist'. Currently that card is the one with the name 'Eiffel Tower'. If I inspect that card I get the following...

```
<div class="list-card-cover js-card-cover" style="background-color: rgb(227, 218, 222); background-image: url(&quot;https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5d7a8bfa10d44f0bf0407de7/600x400/fde821a5a53a83dfb19f4522b81c0f8d/eyeem-26694340-92337801.jpg&quot;); height: 163.333px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

I want the card cover image of the card in that second position of the board each time. Is there a way using xPath or similar where I can say 'I want the card cover image, for whatever card is currently at Card position 2 of List 'Bucket List' on that trello board? This way The image URL can change for each new card that ever appears in that second position, but my email signature will show the correct card cover image each time.

Comment: you can locate the 2 position using this xpath - (//div[@class='list-card-cover js-card-cover'])[3]  .

Comment: what would I do to add that into an email signature with the full URL at front?